# Read Custom tag using linq2xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How can I read the tag  using linq2xml?

```
var q = (from c in xDocument.Descendants("colecciones").Descendants("BoTblPacientes")
                    select c).ToList();
```

but dont work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DalClassObject xmlns="http://www.asd.com">
  <objeto class="BoTblPacientes"></objeto>
  <validador>true</validador>
  <mensaje>El paciente  existe en el sistema .</mensaje>
  <colecciones>
    <BoTblPacientes>
      <tblpacientesmotivoconsulta>5</tblpacientesmotivoconsulta>
      <tblpacientestlfcasa>5</tblpacientestlfcasa>
      <tblpacientescelular>5</tblpacientescelular>
      <tblpacientesoficina>5</tblpacientesoficina>
      <tblpacientescorreo>5</tblpacientescorreo>
      <tblpacientesdireccion>5</tblpacientesdireccion>
      <tblpacientesapellidos>5</tblpacientesapellidos>
      <tblpacientesdocumento>5</tblpacientesdocumento>
      <tblpacientessexoid>0</tblpacientessexoid>
      <tblpacientesfechanacimiento class="sql-date">2012-05-13</tblpacientesfechanacimiento>
      <tblpacientesnombres>5</tblpacientesnombres>
      <tblpacientesid>2</tblpacientesid>
      <tblpacientesestadocivil>0</tblpacientesestadocivil>
      <tblpacientesfecharegistro class="sql-date">2012-05-13</tblpacientesfecharegistro>
      <tblpacienteidmaster>0</tblpacienteidmaster>
    </BoTblPacientes>
    <BoTblPacientes>
      <tblpacientesmotivoconsulta>23232</tblpacientesmotivoconsulta>
      <tblpacientestlfcasa>2332</tblpacientestlfcasa>
      <tblpacientescelular>23</tblpacientescelular>
      <tblpacientesoficina>23</tblpacientesoficina>
      <tblpacientescorreo>23</tblpacientescorreo>
      <tblpacientesdireccion>2323</tblpacientesdireccion>
      <tblpacientesapellidos>ewr</tblpacientesapellidos>
      <tblpacientesdocumento>5</tblpacientesdocumento>
      <tblpacientessexoid>0</tblpacientessexoid>
      <tblpacientesfechanacimiento class="sql-date">2012-03-29</tblpacientesfechanacimiento>
      <tblpacientesnombres>wer</tblpacientesnombres>
      <tblpacientesid>3</tblpacientesid>
      <tblpacientesestadocivil>0</tblpacientesestadocivil>
      <tblpacientesfecharegistro class="sql-date">2012-05-13</tblpacientesfecharegistro>
      <tblpacienteidmaster>0</tblpacienteidmaster>
    </BoTblPacientes>
  </colecciones>
</DalClassObject>
```

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to select?  From your query, it looks like you are trying to create a list of `XElements` that are children of `BoTblPacientes`?

Comment: Hi Antonio, I want to get all  <BoTblPacientes> later fill it in a class.

Comment: @NewCastle79 so you want a list of `BoTblPacientes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial “but doesn't work” statement isn't very helpful as you are not really clarifying what isn't working, but from the error i see, I am going to guess that your query isn't selecting anything.

Your xml root element declares a namespace but you are not specifying that namespace in the query, as a result nothing matches the string you are providing in the `Descendants()` method.

You need to look up by the local name instead

```
var q = (from c in xDocument.Descendants()
         where c.Name.LocalName == "BoTblPacientes"
         select c).ToList()
```

Just for completeness sake, as mentioned by OP in the comments, another option is to add the namespace to the query instead:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.asd.com";
var q = (from c in xDocument.Descendants(ns + "colecciones") 
         select c).ToList();
```

Comment: I get count = 0 this is the problem.

Comment: if I use XNamespace ns = "http://www.asd.com"; 

            XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(txt);
            var q = (from c in xDocument.Descendants(ns + "colecciones")
                     select c).ToList(); works, but if use the where clause dont work

Comment: Sorry, i was working without testing my code and just copied part of your initial query, I have editted my query, please try it now.

Comment: var q = (from c in xDocument.Descendants()
                     where c.Name.LocalName == "BoTblPacientes"
                     select c).ToList();

Comment: @NewCastle79 your option with adding the namespace to the query also works and either is acceptable.  That solution is preferred when you know the namespace and potentially could have multiple nodes with the same name in the same XML, but in different namespaces.  I added that to my answer.  My initial solution will work in cases where you don't necessarily know the namespace but will result in possibily too many matches if you have multiple name spaces.